# Common deadlocks on stored procedure with no index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, deadlock

I'm investigating some deadlocks on a production SQL server 2008 R2 box that all seem to be related to the same stored procedure.

The procedure is very simple.. it updates one column on a table row and finds the row using the identity column (ID).

Looking further into this strangely the Clustered index isn't even set to the identity column and there is no non-clustered index for the column either. I've looked at the Execution Plan which says it's doing a Clustered Index Scan.

Could this be the cause of the deadlocks? And if so would someone mind explaining why? Could it be acquiring page locks? Looking at MSDN documentation it says U locks should prevent common deadlocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will explain this kind of deadlock and how to correct it:

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/sql-server-deadlocks-caused-by-clustered-index-scan/

You are right, it's due to the clustered index scan.  You need to just put a non-clustered index on the identity (ID) column and that should fix it.